# open source codeplex library can be used for a commercial purpose?

Tags: c#, licensing, codeplex

In our solution, we use [SharpCompress library](http://sharpcompress.codeplex.com) which is licensed under MS-PL, for 7z compression.

I wonder when we release a solution (exe) or deliver our source code project containing that SharpCompress library for commercial purpose. Is it right to do so or not?

Comment: Refer this question to your lawyers.  Why would you make a commercially important decision based on the combination of sound advice, complete nonsense and all points between that you see on SO ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing or legal issues, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274963/questions-about-licensing/274964#274964) and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139804/can-licensing-questions-ever-be-on-topic) for details, and the [help] for more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[SharpCompress](http://sharpcompress.codeplex.com/license) is licensed under the Ms-PL license. This license is actually not as restrictive as others (GPL for instance). It's simple and understandable.

If you want to use a compiled version of the library in a commercial project, simply put the SharpCompress binaries (DLL files...etc.) in your project directory, and add a `license.txt` file that links to the [Ms-PL license](http://www.opensource.org/licenses/MS-PL).

See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1424307/how-does-ms-pl-license-work

Answer (score 0):

As you can read [here](http://sevenzipsharp.codeplex.com/license) it is licenced under the terms of the lgpl. You can include it in your project and distribute it commercially as long as you publish any changes to the library.

Comment: I was wrong, It should be SharpCompress, What do you think about it. I have read the license website but I am not quite sure about the terms they described there. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @devn SharpCompress is licenced under the Microsoft Public License (Ms-PL). Ms-PL does not restrict the binary distribution of the library. You can distribute it as part of a commercial product. Ms-PL is not GPL compatible. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shared_source#Microsoft_Public_License_.28Ms-PL.29